# wsdl operation with unlimited parameters

Tags: php, wsdl, soapserver

I have to create WSDL for my SoapServer which passes data from another service. The data which was provided to me has the following structure:

```
<operationName>
    <parameterHeader></parameterHeader>
    <parameterData1></parameterData1>
    <parameterData2></parameterData2>
    ...
    <parameterDataN></parameterDataN>
</operationName>
```

This means that I have to create the method

```
function operationName(parameterHeader, parameterData1, parameterData2, ... parameterDataN){
  ...
}
```

It is impossible to know how many parameters will be provided to my operation.

As a solution, I'm trying to create WSDL for the method without parameters, but inside this method use the function `func_get_args()` to get all parameters.

Unfortunately, I still can't create proper WSDL and I'm not sure if this is possible.

Precise data (example) which should be received by my web service is the following:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <tns:operationResponse xmlns:tns="http://somedomain.com/demo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xmlns="http://anotherdomain.com/anotherdemo">
            <tns:ResponseHeader attrName1="data1" attrName2="data2" attrName3="data3" />
            <tns:ObjectData>
                <tns:ElementData ElementAttr1="data1" ElementAttr2="data2" ElementAttr3="data3"/>
            </tns:ObjectData>
            <tns:ObjectData>
                <tns:ElementData ElementAttr1="data21" ElementAttr2="data22" ElementAttr3="data23"/>
            </tns:ObjectData>
            <tns:ObjectData>
                <tns:ElementData ElementAttr1="data31" ElementAttr2="data32" ElementAttr3="data33"/>
            </tns:ObjectData>
            <tns:ObjectData>
                <tns:ElementData ElementAttr1="data41" ElementAttr2="data42" ElementAttr3="data43"/>
            </tns:ObjectData>
        </tns:operationResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Have you any experience with such kind of WSDL or maybe some ideas about how to get provided structure of the data?

I though about possibility to take into account  as parameter name, so other data could be used as complexType. Maybe WSDL provides some tricks...

Comment: I don't know if the WSDL spec supports this. What's wrong with having one collection parameter and passing in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike, my first approach would be to use an array parameter. While it is possible to imagine unlimited parameters in a procedure, I'm pretty sure the kind of definition in WSDL is just enumerative, so you have to explicitly list your parameters. 
Consider also that some Web Service implementations might not be able to manage unlimited args (in this case, on the requestor side, so it is their problem and not yours).

Comment: Yes, use the array is the right way for this case. But unfortunately I have no possibility to change the format of input data.

Comment: It looks like a poorly designed contract. It should be <operation name="operationName"><paramHeader></paramHeader><paramDataArray><param>1</param><param>2</param><param>3</param>...</paramDataArray></operation>

Comment: I just edited my post and provide more/less precise example. But in the case even this data poorly designed, is it possible to receive this data correctly by SoapServer in PHP.

Comment: I know that this data format already used in other systems, so there it works (but probably with not SoapServer). Off course, I can receive request XML and parse it, but this solution is not OK for me.

Comment: Re-reading your initial question, I'm not sure I understood what you need to do. Do you mean that, independently from the WSDL, the requestor will send you a response with unlimited parameters? I ask this because usually requestors should comply with your WSDL, not the vice versa. In this case, it seems they will ignore your WSDL, since you cannot do the right thing, i.e., transform the parameters to an array. So, no need to have a WSDL file: just create the SoapServer in non-WSDL mode (pass NULL instead of the WSDL parameter in the constructor and set the uri option in the second parameter).

Comment: Sorry guys. Looks like my WSDL file was wrong. I got correct one from the customer and my script can process provided data correctly. Using new WSDL file I have only one parameter <tns:operationResponse> (array with elements <tns:ResponseHeader> and <tns:ObjectData>). So, the first tag in provided data XML is not operation name but parameter name.